# How do I create a UI where I have a tree-view to show my folder-tree and a table to show my files in Vue.js while being able to drag and drop files?

Tags: vue.js

I want to create an UI in Vue.js that looks like the following:

[image]

If the user clicks on a folder or subfolder the table below lists all the files. Simply displaying a treeview and a table by using the element-ui components isn't complicated. I however want to allow the user to drag-and-drop files into the folders and don't know how to go about that.
I would prefer to solve this problem within element-ui but I'm also open to switching to different components.

Comment: Both [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula/blob/master/readme.markdown) and [vuedraggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/README.md) have worked well in past projects. However, I assume you mean drag and drop from a filesystem into your apps ui?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter : I'm not interacting with the filesystem, but with files that I order myself into folders.